# Update data information on the screen/display

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want my application updates the screen information while the code is executing. I tried with `this.LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout();` but it didn't work and I don't understand why. Can anyone help me?
The application receive a button propriety from a button clicked, then use that to a several things in a Model class, and then I want it show a message to the user. after that i want it continue executing more things (AI)... :S

```
public void showMsgFromModel(string player, string msg)
    {
        if(player!="")
            txNomeMsg.Text = player + ":";
        else
            txNomeMsg.Text = player;

        txMsg.Text = msg;
        this.LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do some processing from the UI thread, which is therefore unable to update the interface.

Use a background worker to execute long-running tasks, and use the dispatcher when you need to update the UI:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1500); // Some processing

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => txMsg.Text = "Hello"); // Update the UI

    Thread.Sleep(1500); // More processing
};

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't work, the application continues showing the messages when end to execute all code and not when is asking for to show

Comment: @DianaRodrigues Could you show your code with the background worker? There must be something you're doing wrong.